# How do I convert "3 days" to 3 in Microsoft Excel for OSX

Tags: ms-office

I have a column filled with values like `3 days`, `12 days`, etc

How can I strip out the text and force convert these to integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the column of data.
2. Choose **Data** → **Text to Columns**.
3. Excel should determine the data is delimited. Choose **Next**.
4. Tick **Space** as the delimiter. The preview should indicate the data is split correctly.

   [image]
5. For the first column of numbers, leave **General** selected as the format. If you don't wish to keep the text in a column to the side, select the second column and choose **Do not import column**.

   [image]
6. Choose **Finish** to complete.